# Unity - Move left eye of VR camera

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I am working in the google cardboard environment, and i was wondering how to change the position of one eye in the vr camera system.

My goal is to get both eyes perfectly aligned so they produce the exact same image. Currently unity automatically offsets one eye to give the scene a stereoscopic view. I tried creating two separate cameras, one for left eye and right eye, and then adjusting the position of one until i got both eye to see the same image. However when i tested this on a different phone, the images were offset again.

This problem has been throwing me for a loop and i would greatly appreciate any advise or help!

Thank you!!

Comment: So i found this in the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-stereoMirrorMode.html

Im gonna check if this works

Comment: Nah this gave me mono but i added a stereo camera which broke it. I layered it correctly and the left eye was good, but the right eye was messed up. I put the right eye on depth clear and gave it a higher depth layer than the mono camera, but the mono camera was not rendering for the right eye so only the stereo was rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use GVR SDK 0.6 version, there's lotmore options. And best Unity version for this SDK is 5.6.2.
Here's some useful video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKC1YkpE-8M